# Limit number of sub_menu items to 4

Tags: php

I am trying to limit the number of sub_menu items (li) to maximum of 4. I'm no php developer but gave it a go with some code as provided below.

This is the existing code, which will just keep displaying it all, no limit set right now.

```
if (count($sub_menu_array)) {
        echo '<nav id="sub-nav"><ul>';
        foreach ($sub_menu_array as $sub_menu_row) {
            // print_r($sub_menu_row);
            echo '<li><a href="'.HTTP_HOST.$sub_menu_row['categoryPath'].'">'.strtoupper($sub_menu_row['categoryName']).'</a></li>';
        }

        echo '</ul></nav>';
    } else {
        echo '<nav id="sub-nav"><ul><li></li></ul></nav>';
    }
```

Here is what I tried but it ended up displaying nothing instead.

```
if (count($sub_menu_array)) {
        echo '<nav id="sub-nav"><ul>';
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($sub_menu_array as $sub_menu_row => $v) {
            // print_r($sub_menu_row);
            echo '<li><a href="'.HTTP_HOST.$sub_menu_row['categoryPath'].'">'.strtoupper($sub_menu_row['categoryName']).'</a></li>';
            if (++$i == 3) break;
        }

        echo '</ul></nav>';
    } else {
        echo '<nav id="sub-nav"><ul><li></li></ul></nav>';
    }
```

Comment: Why add "=> $v"? You cast $sub_menu_row as KEY, but not as VALUE

Comment: No idea to be honest, was just looking at an example earlier and tried it out, I'm more front end not back.

Comment: Simply delete "=> $v"

Comment: @rjhdby - perfect, works great now thanks. I almost got it then :). Happy to accept as an answer if you want to put it down as one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syntax of PHP foreach statement has two different variants

```
foreach (array_expression as $value){
    statement
}
foreach (array_expression as $key => $value)
    statement
```

When you chanched code from

```
foreach ($sub_menu_array as $sub_menu_row) {
```

to

```
foreach ($sub_menu_array as $sub_menu_row => $v) {
```

You also changed values what appropriated to $sub_menu_row. For example:

```
$sub_menu_array = array ('a','b');
```

In the first variant at first iteration

```
$sub_menu_row=='a'
```

and in second variant

```
$sub_menu_row==0 #array's element key
$v=='a' #value
```

There are two solutions

1. Simply remove '=> $v'
2. Change $sub_menu_row to $v inside foreach statement

Answer (score 0):

You have changed foreach, you should now use $v as a value.

```
if (count($sub_menu_array)) {
    echo '<nav id="sub-nav"><ul>';
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($sub_menu_array as $sub_menu_row => $v) {
        // print_r($sub_menu_row);
        echo '<li><a href="'.HTTP_HOST.$v['categoryPath'].'">'.strtoupper($v['categoryName']).'</a></li>';
        if (++$i == 3) break;
    }

    echo '</ul></nav>';
} else {
    echo '<nav id="sub-nav"><ul><li></li></ul></nav>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be enough for the menu part:

```
echo '<nav id="sub-nav"><ul>';
$i = 0;
foreach ($sub_menu_array as $sub_menu_row => $v) {
    if($i < 4) {
        echo '<li><a href="'.HTTP_HOST.$sub_menu_row['categoryPath'].'">'.strtoupper($sub_menu_row['categoryName']).'</a></li>';
    }
    $i++;
}

echo '</ul></nav>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Insert this line before displaying the menu

```
$sliced_sub_menu_array = array_slice($sub_menu_array, 0, 4);
```

and then

```
foreach ($sliced_sub_menu_array as $sub_menu_row => $v) {
    // displaying here
}
```

Comment: Or you even can use it like $sub_menu_array = array_slice($sub_menu_array, 0, 4); if you do not have to use whole menu items list later

Answer (score -1):

Use this code .

```
<?php
if (count($sub_menu_array)) {
        echo '<nav id="sub-nav"><ul>';
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($sub_menu_array as $sub_menu_row => $v) {
            // print_r($sub_menu_row);
            echo '<li><a href="'.HTTP_HOST.$sub_menu_row['categoryPath'].'">'.strtoupper($sub_menu_row['categoryName']).'</a></li>';
            if ($i == 3)
            { 
                break;
            }
            $i++;
        }

        echo '</ul></nav>';
    } else {
        echo '<nav id="sub-nav"><ul><li></li></ul></nav>';
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: I won't work. The loop still references key of the array, not a value.

Comment: This code is wrong. $sub_menu_row is KEY of $sub_menu_array, but author needed it's VALUE.